Efficiently find the most recent grouped activities
I have a very simple table called posts.Comment, which has two important columns:

PostId: to which Post belongs this comment
Timestamp: when was the comment written

For an example table setup with dummy data:
CREATE SCHEMA posts;

CREATE TABLE posts.Comment (
   Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
   PostId INT,
   Timestamp DATETIME2
);

WITH Tally(n) AS (
    SELECT TOP (500) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1
    FROM sys.all_objects
)
INSERT INTO posts.Comment (PostId, Timestamp)
SELECT
    FLOOR(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) + a.n) * 10000),
    DATEADD(SECOND,
            ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % (DATEDIFF(SECOND, '2010-01-01', '2025-01-01') + 1),
            '2010-01-01')
FROM Tally a
CROSS JOIN Tally b

CREATE INDEX IX_PostId_Timestamp ON posts.Comment(PostId, Timestamp DESC)
CREATE INDEX IX_Timestamp_PostId ON posts.Comment(Timestamp DESC, PostId)

I want to find 10 posts, that most recently had an activity (comment written), together with the timestamp of the last activity.
So basically I want:
SELECT TOP (10) MAX(Timestamp), PostId
FROM posts.Comment
GROUP BY PostId
ORDER BY MAX(Timestamp) DESC, PostId

Even though I have an appropriate index ON posts.Comment(Timestamp DESC, PostId), the SQL Server still iterates over all rows and groups them, and only afterwards figures out the 10 most recent comments.
See https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hkga8RVX1l
In my case it iterates over all 300k rows, even though the first ~15 rows (with the index sort order) would be enough.
I want to avoid all those row reads (even though it takes on 100ms since 300k is not that large...).

The best solution that I have found so far, is to use the following:
SELECT MAX(Timestamp), y.PostId
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP (10) PostId
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (999999999) Timestamp, PostId
        FROM posts.Comment
        ORDER BY Timestamp DESC, PostId
    ) x
) y 
JOIN posts.Comment ON y.PostId = Comment.PostId
GROUP BY y.PostId

When you order the subquery (together with a TOP blocker), the DISTINCT TOP (10) will use a Unique (Flow Distinct - Hash Match) operator, so it streams all ordered rows and stops once it finds the first 10 distinct rows.
Afaik this operator is not able to give additional values (like the first seen Timestamp), so I need lookup the max values with a JOIN and a second index (this time with the columns arranged in the alternative order - ON posts.Comment(PostId, Timestamp DESC)).
This is instant (<1ms) as it typically reads less than 20 rows, but it's ridiculously complicated (and I'm not sure if this is even stable).
See https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy0ZPAVX1g

Is there anything simpler?
Something that doesn't require jumping through multiple hoops?

did any of the answers below solve your issur?

Your existing query is probably the best you are going to get in terms of simplicity, assuming the first few rows satisfy the query. It's likely to be pretty stable, except that you are guaranteed to query the table twice for every row. So if the final TOP is fairly large that might be a significant issue.
Another option is a skip-scan, ie skip through the index after finding the highest Timestamp and look for the next PostId. Unfortunately, SQL Server does not implement skip-scanning.
@PaulWhite showed how this can be simulated using a recursive CTE. It's rather involved, because the recursive part of the CTE is not allowed to use TOP, so instead you need to use ROW_NUMBER which is transformed into a TOP by the compiler.
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TOP (1)
      c.PostId, c.Timestamp
    FROM Comment c
    ORDER BY Timestamp DESC

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.PostId, c.Timestamp
    FROM (
        SELECT
          c.*,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cte.Timestamp DESC) AS rn
        FROM cte
        JOIN Comment c ON c.Timestamp < cte.Timestamp AND c.Postid <> cte.PostId
    ) c
    WHERE c.rn = 1
)
SELECT TOP (10)
  *
FROM cte;


You can make it slightly more efficient by using an inline Table Valued Function to "hide" the TOP from the CTE so it compiles.
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.TopPost (@afterTimestamp DATETIME2, @excludePostId int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    SELECT TOP (1)
      c.PostId, c.Timestamp
    FROM Comment c
    WHERE c.Timestamp < @afterTimestamp
      AND c.PostId <> @excludePostId
    ORDER BY Timestamp DESC;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TOP (1)
      c.PostId, c.Timestamp
    FROM Comment c
    ORDER BY Timestamp DESC

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.PostId, c.Timestamp
    FROM cte
    CROSS APPLY dbo.TopPost(cte.Timestamp, cte.PostId) c
)
SELECT TOP (10)
  *
FROM cte;


db<>fiddle

I don't have access to a SQL Server instance at the moment, but I tried a couple alternate solutions using SQL Fiddle. As much as I dislike RBAR solutions, the cursor one seemed to work well. As you pointed out, it should only have to look say 15 rows or so into that index to find the 10 rows it needs, and the cursor would do just that.
I wasn't able to get your query to finish when processing 1 million rows, probably due to various load/limitations with the SQL Fiddle website.
You can comment/uncomment the 3 solutions and see how they perform on a real SQL Server.
Here's the test code I was using:
CREATE TABLE Comment
(
    PostId INT NOT NULL,
    Timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL
);

--Fill it up with some test data
INSERT INTO Comment(PostId, Timestamp)
    SELECT value, DATEADD(SECOND, value, GETUTCDATE())
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 1000000);

--update a few to have the same (late) timestamp
UPDATE Comment 
    SET Timestamp = '2199-01-01' 
    WHERE PostId IN (1,2,3);

--and make a couple have old timestamps too
INSERT INTO Comment(PostId, Timestamp) VALUES
(1, '2000-01-01'),
(2, '2000-01-01');

--index it
CREATE INDEX IX_Timestamp_PostId ON Comment(Timestamp DESC, PostId);

DECLARE @RunDate datetime
SET @RunDate=GETDATE()

/*
----------OP's answer (24 ms with 100k rows)------------
SELECT MAX(Timestamp), y.PostId
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP (10) PostId
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (999999999) Timestamp, PostId
        FROM Comment
        ORDER BY Timestamp DESC, PostId
    ) x
) y 
JOIN Comment ON y.PostId = Comment.PostId
GROUP BY y.PostId
--------------------------------------------
*/

/*
-----------My guess (230 ms with 1 million rows)-----------
SELECT TOP 10 WITH TIES * FROM
(
  SELECT
      PostId, 
      MAX(Timestamp) as max_timestamp 
  from Comment
  GROUP BY PostId
) a
ORDER BY max_timestamp DESC
------------------------------------------
*/


---------CURSOR method (17 ms with 1 million rows)---------------
CREATE TABLE ##TempTopNResults(PostId INT, Timestamp DATETIME);
DECLARE @CurrentPostID INT, @CurrentTimestamp DATETIME;
DECLARE cursor_results CURSOR FOR
  SELECT PostId, Timestamp
  FROM Comment
  ORDER BY Timestamp DESC, PostId;

OPEN cursor_results
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_results into @CurrentPostID, @CurrentTimestamp
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO ##TempTopNResults(PostId,Timestamp) SELECT @CurrentPostId, @CurrentTimestamp WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select 1 FROM ##TempTopNResults WHERE PostId = @CurrentPostId); 
    IF 10 <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ##TempTopNResults)
    BEGIN
        BREAK
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_results into @CurrentPostID, @CurrentTimestamp
END
CLOSE cursor_results;
DEALLOCATE cursor_results;
SELECT * FROM ##TempTopNResults;
---------------------------------------------------------------

--print how long the query took
PRINT CONVERT(varchar(20),datediff(ms,@RunDate,GETDATE()))+' milliseconds'


Interesting approach.
It contains a bug, but that one is easy to fix and the fix doesn't ruin the runtime.
You still insert all rows into the temp table, including duplicate PostId values.
Instead you should insert values with:
INSERT INTO ##TempTopNResults(PostId,Timestamp) SELECT @CurrentPostId, @CurrentTimestamp WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select 1 FROM ##TempTopNResults WHERE PostId = @CurrentPostId);

Good catch, that should fix the duplicate PostIds in the temp table. Incidentally, did you try out all 3 queries? I'm curious what the performance of the 3 is on a real server. Also, I updated the code above to include your fix.

I wouldn't call that approach "easier", but it is at least very direct.
(And btw, an index - or primary key - on the PostId also doesn't hurt - and actually helps a lot for larger TOP values. And you can even count the number of inserts yourself with a helper variable and @@ROWCOUNT - at least in SQL Server)

For small TOP values my "complicated" query is still faster.
E.g. my query 0ms, your guess solution 30ms, and the cursor - together with the fix+improvment I suggested - 3ms.
(although I had to add a second index CREATE INDEX IX_PostId_Timestamp ON Comment(PostId, Timestamp DESC) for my query;

For larger TOP (e.g. 500), your CURSOR approach is faster.
Especially because in my solution I need to do a lot of additional lookups in the second index because of the JOIN.
